# Locating build output from Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I have installed Jenkins, and am successfully building a VS 2012 solution.  Which is great.  However, I cannot find where the build output is located?

I assume I'm missing some parameter somewhere, such as system.outdir in TeamCity.  Regardless, where are my files!

Answer (score 2):

The build output is located where your build job put them. Jenkins have a workspace for each job. By default this workspace is :

```
%JENKINS_HOME%\jobs\%jobname%
```

So I guess your build products are somewhere inside the workspace. Since your building with VC, I guess they will be there:

```
%JENKINS_HOME%\jobs\%jobname%\bin
```

Comment: Thanks - I figured it out.  I had mistakenly thought, setting up a Jenkins 'JOB' using only the TFS plugin, was equivalent to creating a build configuration in TeamCity using TFS. 

This was incorrect - I had to add another build step for MSBuild, where the building actually happens.