# Jenkins : System.out.println is not printing anything on console window

Tags: java, jenkins

I am new to jenkins. I have created a demo hello world print java file with following code :

```
public class Hello{
public static void main(String args[]){
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

Saved this file in Jenkins workspace folder. When I build this file using jenkins then on command line i am getting following output :

```
C:\.jenkins\workspace\first_project>javac Hello.java 

C:\.jenkins\workspace\first_project>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But in this console window there is nowhere text as 'Hello World'. Please help me out how can I print this on console window. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`javac Hello.java` means *compile* the program, not run it. You probably want to run it afterwards, e.g. through a shell-command?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins redirects output to per-job logs. In this manner, such output can be differentiated from other jobs, otherwise the output of jobs running in parallel would be very difficult to decipher.

Look at the output for your job in the Jenkins UI, you should find what you are looking for. [Locating build output from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897300/locating-build-output-from-jenkins) covers this as well.

Comment: I am checking console window of Jenkins itself, but didn't find what i am looking for.

Comment: That will not have the output of your job either. The console output of build jobs gets redirected to logs that are for each job. What would happen if each Jenkins job could print to the console? How could you work with that output if multiple jobs were running?

Comment: I went to project(Which I have created in jenkins), then clicked on build1, then clicked on 'Console Output', would it not displayed only that build's output?

Comment: Yes, it should be, but as @lopushen points out, using System.out is a bad practice. Try using his technique to see if the output is generated as expected. Both should work, but using a Logger is far more reliable and flexible for production software.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

Is a bad practice, consider using slf4j or any other logging library
Logs with slf4j looked good on Jenkins on any project I worked on.
Create a logger

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggableClass.class);
```

And log with the severity you need

```
LOG.debug("The message");
```